# Posting a zip file via cURL gives a binary output

Tags: curl, post, zip, multipartform-data, binaryfiles

I am using a Virtualization Software that allows me to update a running virtual service with a POST request. The post request works when it is done via provided UI in the web browser. It also generates a curl command on the web page.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:1505/lisa-virtualize-invoke/api/v3/vses/VSE/services/API_Test_22" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "deploy=true" -F "inputFile1=@updateCustomer.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed"
```

However when I try to use provided curl command in bash it does not work. I need to be able to use curl for jenkinsfile.

I have tried different variations of 'inputFile1' like:

```
-F "inputFile1=@updateCustomer.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed"
-F "inputFile1=@updateCustomer.zip"
```

In GitBash I get back a gibberish non-ASCII characters as my output.

In Ubuntu terminal I get a different error:

```
curl -X POST -H "authorization: Basic xxx"  "http://10.0.2.2:1505/lisa-virtualize-invoke/api/v3/vses/VSE/services/API_Test_22" -H  "accept: application/zip" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "deploy=true" -F "inputFile1=@\"updateCustomer.zip\""
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

My output in Jenkins is:

```
+ curl -X POST -H authorization: Basic xxx http://10.0.2.2:1505/lisa-virtualize-invoke/api/v3/vses/VSE/services/API_Test_22 -H accept: application/zip -H Content-Type: multipart/form-data -F deploy=true -F inputFile1=@updateCustomer.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 63261    0     0  100 63261      0  52325  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 52325
100 63261    0     0  100 63261      0  28599  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 28599
100 63261    0     0  100 63261      0  19682  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 19689
100 63261    0     0  100 63261      0  15004  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 15008
100 63261    0     0  100 63261      0  12121  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 12121
100 63261    0     0  100 63261      0  10165  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
100 63971    0   710  100 63261    103   9220  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--   152PK�S�N    .maraudit����n�q�w � �4���g���ؤ��(�T�l�o @�1r�~����} &-������U�ƨ���������>���������o�_��g��W�����?���_~�����?��7��~˟����7�����7����?���_�~�B��?��/b����2��h���C�!���������������/ ...
```

Comment: `-H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` - that header is incomplete, missing the boundary. the header should look something like `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5469ff03b90ec969` .. and curl should auto-generate it, you should not set it yourself.

Comment: as for the gibberish binary data, you send the header `-H  "accept: application/zip"` which is telling the server `i want my response in gzip-format`, which is a binary format.. so you are requesting a binary response, and that's what you get.

Comment: your second comment is an answer to my question, it seems to be working fine when changed to -H "accept: application/zip" , please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it:)

Comment: nah, for all i know, the problem could be that you're not quoting your arguments. ill let someone else answer this one

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my previous comment, I wanted to write that I changed the part you said was wrong to  -H  "accept: application/json" and that made it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary output was caused by -H "accept: application/zip". After replacing that with -H "accept: application/json" I had no longer this problem.